# Vlookup returns N/A despite of existing match

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`. I execute `VLOOKUP` function in order to fill in 3 columns from `table2` into `table1`.

For some reason, the formula doesn't work for the first row, and doesn't find the exact match from `table2` even though it exists.

I made sure that both columns (for comparison) have the same format (`General`) and there is no extra spacing. Same conditions also apply for the rest of the records, and it works there properly.

**table1** - you can see the missing matches for the first row.
[image: table1]

**table2** - you can see the match does exist, but it is not reflected in `table1`.
[image: table2]

Is there any other reason why `VLOOKUP` can't find a match for a specific record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try directly evaluating equality for the two cells that you believe are equal, for instance if A2 is the value you are looking up and Sheet2!A100 is the value you think should match try this in a cell:

```
=(A2=Sheet2!A100)
```

If that returns false then you know that there is some formatting issue or error in your vlookup.

Also try Formulas / Evaluate Formula ribbon command to step through your vlookup in case that highlights something wrong.

Comment: The expression returns True.

Update: after refreshing the data and saving the file, I tried to execute VLOOKUP again for the first row, by copy-paste the formula from the second row. Its worked!
I don't know what was the problem, but it's fixed now...
Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you change the vlookup formula to `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:H,7,False)` and see if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Okay - Here's a doozy of a use-case.  `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX-MATCH` were returning **#N/A** for values that were "apparently" equal.  Cleaned my data with `=TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160)," ")))` and that didn't work.

Then, I compared two cells that looked like they had matching values and they evaluated to FALSE (`A1=B1` resulted in **FALSE**).

Then, as a last resort, I code checked each ASCII value for each character in the two cells and I found that the "-" in one cell was different from the "-" in the other cell.  The first cell has the ASCII value 63 and the second cell had the ASCII value 45 for what looked like was the same "-".  Turns out that 63 is a "short dash" and 45 is your standard dash or minus symbol.

The way to evaluate the ASCII codes for each character in a string is to combine the CODE function with the MID or RIGHT functions after testing the cells for length using the LEN function.

Examples:

`LEN(A1)` should equal `LEN(B1)`

For the first character in each cell:

`CODE(A1)` Code defaults to the first character on the left
`CODE(MID(A1,2,1)` yields the ASCII for the second character
`CODE(MID(A1,3,1)` yields the ASCII for the second character
and so on

If you have a lot of characters you can post an integer sequence next to your CODE-MID function and point the position argument to the related integer and just copy down or across

Or

You can look for the weird non-numeric character and just test that one for both cells.

Answer (score 1):

Have observed scenarios like this where direct comparison fails (e.g. formula `=A1=B1` resulted in `FALSE`) and yet length `=LEN(A1)=LEN(B1)` and letter by letter ASCI comparison (`=CODE(A1,1,1)`, `=CODE(A1,2,1)`, `=CODE(A1,3,1)`, etc.) shows no difference.

What worked was to adjust the format of the lookup value inside the VLOOKUP.

e.g.
`=VLOOKUP(A1, ARRAY, COL_NUM, FALSE)` -> `=VLOOKUP(TEXT(A1, "000"), ARRAY, COL_NUM, FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an issue I encountered: my VLOOKUP formula returns the correct value (1) if I type in the value-to-look-up (1.016) directly in the formula, shown in cell `F54`.

However, if I referenced a value in column `A` as the value-to-look-up, the formula returned `#N/A`, as shown in cell `F55`.

*(I was actually trying to VLOOKUP the current row's A value plus 0.015, i.e. `VLOOKUP(A54+0.015, $A$3:$B$203, 2, FALSE)`)*

Yet if I use the `ROUND` function, then the VLOOKUP formula works, as shown in `F56`.

[image: Excel VLOOKUP issue]

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issue and resolved it by changing the vlookup formula to =VLOOKUP([value to lookup], [lookup table], [column to return in the lookup table], **False**).  Setting the last input argument to "false" forces Excel vlookup function to perform an exact match.